# .Net HttpClient Class within Xamarin only works in Full Debug info mode

Tags: c#, debugging, xamarin

I'm new in Xamarin development.I build a small demo which use .Net Httpclient to send and receive message from remote server.Everything is fine except the httpclient segament

If I choose Debug and output full debug info the response is "Success".
If I choose Debug and output pdb-only or none then I got into the Exception.
Things are same when I build Release, but if I output none debug info with Release mode the App will crash on my cell phone.

Does anybody have the similar problem ? 
What should I do? I will greatly appreciate a solution.

The related code is:

```
    string response = string.Empty;
    var client = new HttpClient();
    client.MaxResponseContentBufferSize = 1024 * 1024;
    //client.Timeout = new TimeSpan( 0, 0, 0, 5 );
    Task<string> result = null;
    try
    {
        result = client.GetStringAsync( reqInfo_ );
        response = result.Result;
        response = "Success";
    }
    catch ( Exception e )
    {
        //output the exception
    }
```

Exception is:

[image]

Comment: You have to include the code in question as text in the question. Also when you get exceptions or other errors you have to include them. Just saying there is an exception doesn't say anything.

Comment: Is there a reason that you call an async method just to wait for it in the very next line?

Comment: Is it XForms or Classic? Where is this code, PCL or on platform? Need _reqInfo to reproduce

Comment: Hi, Sami, thank you for the help. I added the code and what the Exception really is . I can't figure it out why I get these Exceptions when I don't output full debug info.

Answer (score 0):

http://forums.xamarin.com/discussion/7327/system-net-webexception-error-nameresolutionfailure
Owen's solution works for me:
"For me, in release mode, I checked the box marked Internet in the Required permissions section of the AndroidManifest.xml file found under the Properties folder. Debug mode doesn't need this checked but Release mode does - which you need if sending the APK by email for installation - which works great by the way. In case anyone is interested, you also have to sign your app and produce the private key following these instructions here: http://developer.xamarin.com/guides/android/deployment,testing,_and_metrics/publishing_an_application/part_2-_publishing_an_application_on_google_play/"